# How do I create a slideshow of images in a tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a slideshow of images with tkinter but only the first image will display. Here is an MCVE of my code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

# create window
window = Tk()
window.geometry('1000x1000')


# function to display a series of images with a delay of 3seconds between each
def slideshow():
    for i in range(3):
        entry.delete(0, END)
        canvas.delete("all")
        entry.insert(0, str(i))
        path = ('image' + str(i) + '.png')
        image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
        canvas.create_image(100, 100, anchor=CENTER, image=image)
        window.after(3000)
        window.mainloop()

# create widgets
buttonDisplayImages = Button(window, width=30, height=15, text='Display Images', command=lambda: slideshow())
entry = Entry(window, width=35, borderwidth=2)
canvas = Canvas(window, width=300, height=300)

buttonDisplayImages.grid(row=2, column=1)
entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
canvas.grid(row=3, column=1)

window.mainloop()
```

When I press the button, only the first image will display and, when I close the window, I get the error:

> _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!entry"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should not call `window.mainloop()` inside the for loop and add `canvas.image = image` and `canvas.update_idletasks()` before `window.after(3000)`.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks a lot!