# Python tkinter GUI change Image dynamically

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter

i come from java and just want to create a gui with a picture, but the picture is changing dynamically and i do not know which picture it is going to be ... but it doesnt work like nothing i can just create a image and cannot change it outside of root.mainloop() and get tons of erros messages...
Does someone know how to change the image dynamically ?
Thank you very much

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def add_image_to_gui(root, image_path):
    # Load image
    image = Image.open(image_path)
    # Convert image to Tkinter-compatible format
    tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    # Create label and display image
    image_label = tk.Label(root, image=tk_image)
    image_label.image = tk_image  # Keep reference to the image to prevent it from being garbage collected
    image_label.pack()

def create_gui(window_title, window_size, image_path):
    # Create Tkinter window
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title(window_title)
    root.geometry(window_size)

    # Add image
    add_image_to_gui(root, image_path)

    # Start Tkinter event loop
    root.mainloop()

    return root

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window_title = "Simple GUI"
    window_size = "1495x1020"
    image_path = "Bilder/Hauptfenster.png"
    root = create_gui(window_title, window_size, image_path)
```

ChatGPT, Googling but no one seems to have the same problem like me....

Comment: Have a look on this question and [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64180295/20851944).

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by *"i do not know which picture it is going to be"*.  Pleae elaborate more.  Also you said you *get tons of error messages*, so post what you have tried and the error traceback, i.e you should provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to switch the image after some time you will need to call a function of some type to change it. Since this GUI has no buttons, it is easiest just to schedule the update some time in the future using `tkinter.Tk().after`, and have that function change the label image.

Here is some example code that shows how you might accomplish that with minimal alterations:

EDIT: Updated with the additional information in comments that another function will provide filepaths, which the call to `function_that_yields_new_image_paths` will be replaced with.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

def add_image_to_gui(root):
    image_label = tk.Label(root)
    image_label.pack()
    return image_label

def update_image(root, image_label):
    image = Image.open(function_that_yields_new_image_paths())
    tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    image_label.configure(image=tk_image)
    image_label.image = tk_image
    root.after(1000, update_image, root, image_label)

def function_that_yields_new_image_paths():
    import numpy
    image_path1 = "a.png"
    image_path2 = "b.png"
    return numpy.random.choice((image_path1, image_path2))

def create_gui(window_title, window_size):
    # Create Tkinter window
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title(window_title)
    root.geometry(window_size)

    # Add image
    image_label = add_image_to_gui(root)
    root.after(1, update_image, root, image_label)
    # Start Tkinter event loop
    root.mainloop()

    return root

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window_title = "Simple GUI"
    window_size = "1495x1020"

    root = create_gui(window_title, window_size)
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: yeah but i dont know the image which will be used so i need a method to change the image multiple times after the gui is created

Comment: The code as shown above does change images once a second while the GUI is running (after it is created).
How does your script find out about the new images? Are they just dumped into a directory? Are you expecting user input? Is the file it already points to changed? If you can provide some more details I may be able to update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Well thank you, i will get the image from another function so while runtime i have to to change to image ... why is this so difficult in java's GUI its pretty easy ...

Comment: Given that new information that another function can provide the filepaths I have altered the mockup to show you how that can be done, and simplified it a little. Let me know if you still have any issues.

Comment: okay i will check it tomorrow in detail its geettin late .... ty

Comment: and i think it would be better if the funktion calls the update method otherwise update image method has to guess when the new picture is ready

Answer (score 0):

> Does someone know how to change the image dynamically?

Without using `open` filenames.

- Add namespace `from itertools import cycle`

Snippet:

```
from itertools import cycle
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, image_files, x, y, delay):
        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        
        self.geometry('+{}+{}'.format(x, y))
        self.delay = delay
        
        self.pictures = cycle((tk.PhotoImage(file=image), image)
                              for image in image_files)
        self.picture_display = tk.Label(self)
        self.picture_display.pack()

        
    def show_slides(self):
        '''cycle through the images and display them'''
        
        img_object, img_name = next(self.pictures)
        self.picture_display.config(image=img_object)
        
        self.title(img_name)
        self.after(self.delay, self.show_slides) 

DELAY = 1000
 
image_files = [
'p1.png',
'p2.png',
'p3.png',
'p4.png',
'p5.png',
'p6.png'
]

X = 100
Y = 50

app = App(image_files, X, Y, DELAY)
app.show_slides()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: yeah but the problem is if the gui is running i want to change the images based on what happens on my screen, so i dont know the exact images

Comment: Do you want to know the name of filename(s)?